# React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies - Loading indicator with eslint-disable-next-line warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

**Explaining the scenario:**

Currently working on a `React` project with a small search functionality connected to `Redux`. In the scenario on the search result page - which is a functional component - when the user scrolls down till the bottom of the screen it will trigger to fetch the next following items, basically implementing infinite scroll.

My solution works as expected, only the warning message bugs me.

**Code snippets, warning message:**

In the below example I have removed several other lines of code which does not related to this problem. I have tried to add here a minimalist example which I could explain my scenario with. I have removed the paging, offset and other variables which are related to the infinite scroll.

Reason behind why the code separates the `doSearch` functionality into a `Redux` store is it is used in different component as well. For example in the `Home` page the search is triggered before redirecting to the `Result` page.

In the `Result` I have the following:

```
const Result = (props) => {
    const {search, doSearch} = props;
    const {isInProgress} = search;

    const onScroll = useCallback(() => {
        // removed additional checks if user reached the bottom of the screen
        if (!isInProgress) {
            // on start => isInProgress = true;
            // on finish => isInProgress = false;
            doSearch();
        }
    }, [doSearch]); // removed isInProgress => warning message

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    }, [onScroll]);

    // ... rest of the code
}
```

In the `search` reducer you can see the following:

```
const initialState = {
    isInProgress: false,
    assets: [],
    // ...
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Consts.FETCH_ASSETS_SUCCESS:
            const { data } = action.response;
            return {
                ...state,
                assets: data.assets,
                isInProgress: false,
                // ...
            };
        case Consts.SET_SEARCH_IN_PROGRESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isInProgress: true
            };
        // ... rest of the reducer
    }
};
```

In the `action` where the `doSearch` is happening:

```
export const doSearch = () => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: Consts.SET_SEARCH_IN_PROGRESS});

    // ... rest of the code

    let response = await assetsService.getAssets();

    dispatch(response.status === 200 ?
        {type: Consts.FETCH_ASSETS_SUCCESS, response: response}:
        {type: Consts.FETCH_ASSETS_ERROR, error: response});
}
```

The warning message what terminal shows:

> React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'isInProgress'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

**Questions:**

If I add the `isInProgress` variable into the dependency array then it will be triggered infinitely. Once the fetch finished the value of `isInProgress` changes to `false` which starts again the `doSearch`.

Obviously I could ignore it by adding this following snippet into the hook:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

But I feel like adding this line it is just avoiding further problems.

*So my questions are:*

1. Is there any other solution to avoid the mentioned warning message?
2. Any other solution, best practice or advice to restructure the above shared code snippets?

Any idea is highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @gerasalus Nope, even after a clean up I ended up with the same, disabling warning so currently still using with `// eslint-disable-next-line`. Probably using the `isInProgress` within the component would be the best option and not from the Redux store. Using `const [isInProgress, setIsInProgress] = useState(false)` can be one solution I believe in order to eliminate the warning.